# Creating a global object or multiple local object

Tags: java, android

If I have a class OnlineDataRetrieval which I need to use time to time in my Activity, is it wise to open a global object for that class and reuse that object throughout the lifespan of the activity, Or I should just create a local Object every time I need to use that class?

So basically I want to know which of the options below is preferable from performance point of view?

**Option 1**

```
public class Activity extends Activity {
    OnlineDataRetrieval onlineDataRetrieval;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        onlineDataRetrieval = new OnlineDataRetrieval(this);
    }
    public void methodA(){
        onlineDataRetrieval.callSomeMethod();
    }
    public void methodB(){
        onlineDataRetrieval.callSomeMethod();
    }
    public void methodC(){
        onlineDataRetrieval.callOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
public class Activity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    }
    public void methodA(){
        OnlineDataRetrieval onlineDataRetrieval = new OnlineDataRetrieval(this);
        onlineDataRetrieval.callSomeMethod();
    }
    public void methodB(){
        OnlineDataRetrieval onlineDataRetrieval = new OnlineDataRetrieval(this);
        onlineDataRetrieval.callSomeMethod();
    }
    public void methodC(){
        OnlineDataRetrieval onlineDataRetrieval = new OnlineDataRetrieval(this);
        onlineDataRetrieval.callOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: calling a constructor many times is most likely slower than getting an existing reference from memory...

Comment: That was my thought in favor of option 1, however I am a bit confused about a statement I have read somewhere: "It’s important that we dispose the objects we no longer need or use and free up the memory for other uses." ... in option 1, I am keeping the object for the lifespan of the Activity, though I might not use that for long (may be not at all in some cases)

Comment: You asked "from performance point of view". Managing object lifetimes is a maintainability concern.

Comment: Well actually I am just thinking whether it would cause out of memory issue if I always follow such convention.

Comment: Interesting thing is this question got 4 votes to close with the reason that the answer will be "primarily opinion-based" ... does that mean there is no answer for this?

Comment: I voted to "keep open" - you specified the POV so an objective answer is possible.

Comment: Yaa I thought so, but apparently it will be automatically closed after 1 more vote ... anyway, can you please let me know your thought whether option 1 might cause any Out Of Memory issue? I mean is it okay/advisable if I follow that as a general practice? Thanks for your opinion though.

Comment: In Java, to destroy an object, you need to destroy all references to it (then it'll be garbage-collected eventually). Specifically, for the global object - set the global  variable to `null` at some point when you no longer need it and make sure no one else will keep another reference to the object indefinitely.

Comment: googling for "java prevent memory leaks" gives plenty of more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is object oriented. Every time you initialize the new instance of the class, you are making a new object. If you don't need to make new instances, then the option where you are calling the method from the class is acceptable.

It is as simple as making an object once and calling a method from it three times vs. creating the object three different times and calling the same method from three different objects.

Performance-wise, I would go with option 1.

Comment: I am a bit confused about a statement I have read somewhere: "It’s important that we dispose of the objects we no longer need or use and free up the memory for other uses." ... in option 1, I am actually keeping the object for the lifespan of the Activity, though I might not call that object for a long time (let say MethodA, B and C are called by a button action). So, should I do that?

Comment: It really depends on how often you use the object in your program. If you only use it a little bit, then creating an instance of it in three methods might actually work out better. It seems to me that you need to call it a couple of times. If you make the object once and call the methods a few times, you are still only using the one object. If you're using threads to make your calls, you may end up with hundreds of new objects before garbage collection kicks in. It depends on your program and how you're going to use it.